# My Amazon Web Service (AWS) connection type is not in my Airflow, even though the package/provider has been installed in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-connections

I'm new to this stackoveflow and I want to ask about connection types in my Airflow. My connection type does not have Amazon Web Services (AWS), even though it is already installed in my Airflow environment and my Airflow version is the latest, namely 2.7.1 and of course it is included in the requirements for installing Amazon providers, but I have installed it and it still doesn't work. it's in my connection type. I wonder why that is, guys? Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvqNZ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa0mv.png)

I want to know why this happened, guys. Can you explain why and what is the solution?